# Why should a struct's size reflect its alignment?

Tags: c, size, padding, memory-alignment

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Typical_alignment_of_C_structs_on_x86):

> the last member is padded with the number of bytes required so that the total size of the structure should be a multiple of the largest alignment of any structure member

In my understanding, it means that in the following:

```
struct A {
  char *p;     // 8 bytes
  char c;      // 1 byte
};
struct B {
  struct A a;  // 16 bytes
  char d;      // 1 bytes
};
```

Struct `A` will have a size of 16 bytes, and struct `B` will have a size of 24 bytes.

The common explanation is that arrays of `A` should have their elements accessible at the address of the array plus the index times the size of `A`.

But I fail to see why that is the case. Why could we not say `A` has size 9 and `B` has size 10 (both with 8 bytes alignment), and use a special "array-storage" size when indexing into an array?

Of course, we'd still store those types in arrays in a way compatible with their alignment (using 16 bytes to store each `B` element). Then, we'd simply compute element addresses by taking into account their alignment, instead of considering their size alone (the compiler can do that statically).

For example, we could store 64 objects in a 1Kb bytes array of `B`'s, instead of only 42.

Comment: Optimization usually, reading data on a CPU native word boundary might be quicker on some platforms than reading unaligned data (like having to read two words and mask out the wanted word if the data is unaligned).

Comment: Put a different way, this is a software specification that is not for the direct benefit of software. Rather, it's to cooperate with hardware which, most of the time, is either better with such alignment or in some extreme cases, will crash (throw a hardware exception which software must deal with or crash) if used without such alignment.

Comment: Note that I am never talking about not respecting alignment constraints.

Comment: If the value of `sizeof(A)` cannot be guaranteed to be same whether the object is in an array, in another `struct`, or by itself, I can see problems in pointer arithmetic and when allocating memory using `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

In each translation unit of C, `sizeof(T)` is the same, regardless of the context of `T`.  Your proposal would introduce at least two values for `sizeof(T)`: one for arrays of `T` and a different one for individual objects of `T`.  This basically introduces context-dependence into the `sizeof` operator.  It is incompatible with how C handles pointers, arrays, and addresses of objects.

Consider the following:

```
void zero_A(struct A *a) { memset(a,0,sizeof(*a)); }

/* ... */
struct A single;
struct A several[3];
struct B b;

b.d = 3;
zero_A(&b.a);
zero_A(&single);
zero_A(several+1);
```

Under your proposal, `zero_A` would have to know whether the pointer it was passed pointed to `struct A` in an array context (where `sizeof(*a) == 16`) or `struct A` outside of an array context (where `sizeof(*a) == 9`).  Standard C doesn't support this.  If the compiler guessed wrong, or the information was lost (eg: in a round-trip through a `volatile struct A *`), then `zero_A(&single)` would invoke undefined behavior (by writing past the bounds of `single`), and `zero_A(&b.a)` would overwrite `b.d` and also invoke undefined behavior.

Tightly packing structs into an array is a relatively uncommon requirement, and adding context-dependence to `sizeof` would introduce a lot of complications to the language, its libraries, and ABIs.  There are times you need to do this, and C gives you the tools you need: `memcpy` and unions.

Comment: In my idea, the `sizeof` **operator** would always return the real size (not the padded size), thus it would not need to be contextual. And AFAIK you need not zero-out padding bits (do C standards say anything about that?), so you could use the `memset` safely inside `zero_A`.

The only real change that would be done is when adding 1 to an `A*` pointer: it would need to add the *padded size* to the pointer value (call it `psizeof(T)`). Now I realize this would not work to iterate on a bunch of contiguous fields of the same type in a struct. Maybe the C standard require that to be possible?